# Why can't catch this change event with eventListener?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, plugins, wordpress-shortcode

We are writing a WordPress plugin with multiple shortcodes in React, and we need to catch this Datepicker's change event outside it's shortcode, how can we achive this?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datepicker

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
...

 <DatePicker
    selected={pickupDate ?? new Date(moment().startOf("hour"))}
    onChange={(date) => setPickupDate(date)}
    showTimeSelect
    timeFormat="HH:mm"
    timeIntervals={60}
    timeCaption="time"
    dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
    popperPlacement="top-start"
    todayButton="Ma"
    id={`pickup${props.eventid}`}
  />
```

```
let pickup = document.querySelector(`#pickup${props.eventid}`);
pickup.addEventListener("change", calculateInvoiceTotal);
```

Comment: Is the value of id selector is getting change? No... Than you cannot get change event!

Comment: yes, its changes by user's selection. I want to catch that event